# Mobile geolocation precision - cordova / phonegap

Tags: mobile, cordova, gps, geolocation

I want to develop an app that detects how far the user/device is from points on a map.
Calculating the distance is easy, but when you get close to about 30meters I would need it to be as precise as possible.

Basically I want some lights on the UI to get brighter the closer you get to the target/point.

How do I achieve this if the gps position sometimes bounces around for 5-10 meters or more?
Any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general there is the inaccuracy with the position, and indeed its meters, thus the bouncing will be there and its rather impossible to get rid of it, anyways, one suggestion would be to collect the last few (3-10 up to you and your logic really) locations and calculate average from them. Then with fast movements your position would be lagging of course, but when doing slow movements the position shown should be more stable.. Of course you could also have additional logic on determining the movement direction, and accepting the location change towards that faster etc.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response.
The issue with this is that i cannot wait for 10 readings as it takes at least 1 second to get a new one and a person walking will move about a lot meaning i cant have any semi-smooth animation

Answer (score 0):

You will not get a better precision than 3m to the target.
At low, speed, like walking, you will no make it better than 8-10m.

Count the distance sicne last used fix, If it exceeds 12m then use the fix, and mark it as last used.

This is a simple filter which works well for walking speeds.
At speeds higher (> 10km/h) switch off the filter. 
GPS should not jump at that speed.